# Do they say 'a vertical of authority' in English (like, from a top boss to a lowest subordinate)?

Tags: word-request

If not, how do I express that otherwise? I know the expression 'chain of command', but it doesn't seem fit for my purpose. I need to say 'reinforce the vertical of authority', meaning "to make the hierarchical structure more manageable, allow less freedom for the subordinate bodies or people". 'Reinforce the chain' sounds stupid.

Comment: There have been plane crashes attributed to an excessively steep "authority gradient" (sometimes called the "Captain God syndrome") where a senior, older, aircraft captain makes a mistake and the more junior cockpit crew are afraid to say anything. It is stronger during stressful situations. Likewise "Doctor God syndrome". Although it is not confined to any particular culture or society, some are more prone to this problem than others. There is extensive discussion of the syndrome in the literature of safety and of management.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A chain of command is usually vertical by definition.

There is the top of the chain of command and the levels under it.

So, you can refer to a level of command that runs from the top to the bottom or from top to bottom.

The levels of the chain of command.

to **strengthen** the levels of the chain of command
to **strengthen** (hierarchical) reporting relationships
**to tighten [his, her, the presidential etc.] chain of command**

the hierarchy of reporting relationship: a person at a lower level reports to the person above  her or him.

This definition is as good as any:

In an organizational structure, “chain of command” refers to a company's hierarchy of reporting relationships – from the bottom to the top of an organization, who must answer to whom. The chain of command not only establishes accountability, it lays out a company’s lines of authority and decision-making power. A proper chain of command ensures that every task, job position and department has one person assuming responsibility for performance.

[chain of command](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/chain-command-organizational-structure-59110.html)

BBC News:

Change in structure

The bank's plan is to **tighten the chain of command**, cutting the four operating units of its business to two
[tighten the chain of command](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/business/1435300.stm)

New York Times

The shake-up, scheduled to take effect in the next two months, is supposed to **tighten the chain of command** and reduce possible confusion in the case of an emergency. The current chain of command has three layers between the Joint Chiefs of Staff and the commanders of individual ships in the Persian Gulf or in nearby waters.

[tighten the chain of command](https://www.nytimes.com/1987/12/18/world/us-reorganizing-the-gulf-command.html)

Book on Russian oil:

It has proved easy, in other words, to expand the federal government and **tighten the chain of command** [...]

[tighten the chain of command](https://books.google.com/books?id=GSH3PhvD82MC&pg=PA393&lpg=PA393&dq=Russia%20%2B%20%22tighten%20the%20chain%20of%20command%22&source=bl&ots=A_6yujh8ve&sig=ACfU3U2YNyzuFgV0E_A8LRtBG91nluZ7Cw&hl=en&ppis=_e&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiW_Oiwhu3lAhWszlkKHcs_BtsQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Russia%20%2B%20%22tighten%20the%20chain%20of%20command%22&f=false)

Comment: No, I need one singular noun, if possible. What can be used instead of the word 'vertical' in a sentence like 'During his first two terms, Vladimir Putin made considerable efforts to reinforce the presidential vertical.'

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev The word is hierarchy. However, I would use: Mr. Putin **tightened the presidential chain of command**.

Comment: I know that word. But do they say 'strengthen the hierarchy' or 'reinforce the hierarchy'?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Don't you think I would have said that if it sounded better?? I now think chain of command is better **here** regarding Putin. "**tightening a chain" (of command)** is very strong. reinforce troops, or a wall or an argument. loose chain/tight chain, you see?

Comment: Wordy. It's like, what?, six words? In Russian, it's just three. And if an English translation has more words than the Russian original, then there's something wrong with the translation, because Russian is the wordy one, not English

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Look, I am not a Russian-to-English translator, but I am a translator. I can assure you that **tighten his chain of command** is **not wordy** at all in English.

Comment: It doesn't sound natural. It sounds as if someone artificially translated some foreign phrase instead of finding an analog of that phrase in a foreign language. You will probably say that this description more applies to 'a presidential vertical' but at least it's not wordy. Can I just say 'presidential chain' or it wouldn't be clear?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev You must be kidding me, it  could not be more idiomatic. I suggest you google: **tighten the chain of command** [but outside of site:.ru]. And I ask you: **Are you telling me what sounds translated in English**?? Please, spare me.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev We don't normally do crossword puzzles here, so please refrain from framing your questions / further requests in that direction. In general, a one-to-one correspondence between the source and target languages needn't exist in terms of vocabulary, and the same is true for word count. I don't know if you've noticed, but English, unlike Russian, has articles, and is quite understaffed in the cases department, so in the five-word phrase *tighten the chain of command*, the definite article is used, as well as *of*, denoting belonging, neither of which yields extra words in Russian.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker of English, but *chain of command*, together with whatever sort of operations may be performed on it (*tightening*, *loosening*, *strengthening*, *establishing*), sounds perfectly fine to my ears. It's a common phrase in English, really. My conclusion is therefore that you are, will all due respect, out of your depth here when you claim this phrase "sounds translated" to you.